# Injecting $mdMenu into scope. Cannot read property open() of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-material

I am trying to get the Angular Material Design menu to work but I don't seem to be able to use the $mdMenu that is supposed to be injected by the ng-click.

My HTML markup:

```
<div layout="column" layout-fill ng-controller="AuthControl">
    <md-toolbar ng-controller="navigationControl">
        <div ng-controller="menu as ctrl">
          <md-menu>
             <md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="ctrl.open($mdMenu, $event)">
               <md-icon>menu</md-icon>
             </md-button>
             <md-menu-content width="4">
                <md-menu-item>
                   <md-button>
                       <md-icon>account_circle</md-icon>
                   </md-button>
                </md-menu-item>
             </md-menu-content>
         </md-menu>
      </div>
   </md-toolbar>
</div>
```

The Angular Controller:

```
controllers.controller('menu', function menuControl($mdDialog) {
   var originatorEv;

   this.open = function($mdMenu, ev) {
     originatorEv = ev;
     $mdMenu.open(ev);
   };
});
```

The contoller gets injected properly but when I run I get the Error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'open' of undefined
```

Does anybody know how to fix this?
Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Instead of **`mdMenu`**, pass **`mdOpenMenu`**

```
  <md-button aria-label="menu" class="md-fab md-mini md-primary" ng-click="ctrl.openMenu($mdOpenMenu, $event)">
```

**Controller:**

```
 this.openMenu = function($mdOpenMenu, ev)     {
      originatorEv = ev;
      $mdOpenMenu(ev);
    };
```

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/sajeetharan/pen/GrGJwZ)**

Comment: Worked like a charm thx. Do you know why this worked and the example provided in the documentation doesn't? How come $mdMenu is not defined?

Comment: I bet it was changed and the demo is still using an older version of angular material.

Comment: `$mdOpenMenu` is deprecated, as noted in the other answer.

Answer (score 8):

"$mdOpenMenu" [has been replaced](https://github.com/angular/material/commit/1e4ba35d4d7b3ec15b482863a6d60def1b760117) by "$mdMenu.open" and is now deprecated. Use the latest version of Angular Material and it will work just fine.

[image]